# PAM : Reject the standard password

Tags: password, pam

I want to reject our standard password in pam for the services until the user change it. It is a fixed password, well known by our users, but I don't know how I can configure pam to refuse it. I check cracklib, but it works only on password change, not on auth. I can't use pam_succeed_if as it doesn't check the password.

Any idea how reject this password ?

Answer (score 2):

`chage -d 0 username` should do it. You might have to set a null initial password which probably isn't very secure but some trial and error testing should reveal if that's the case.

-edit-

In that case can you spawn a login script upon login using `/etc/profile`, `/etc/bash.bashrc` or similar to set that password first and then let them ageing policy force it to be changed ?

Comment: I can't define a null password. I see that I can reject all the connections by pam for null passwords, but I would like to do this with a defined (specific) password.

Comment: I can't start the login script (it is mail servers without interactive shell), pam is just use to test the password and allow the connection.

Comment: Tricky. Hopefully someone else can help.

Answer (score 2):

Consider [pam_exec](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_exec)

Comment: In last option, I will. But I would like to have quick login checks and no process cretaion if it is possible

Comment: Well, if you'd had thousands of log-ins every second this could really matter. In that interesting case I'd write my own PAM-module targeted for this task only. ;-)

Comment: You are right, I can do that. If there is no easy way to do that